# Calculate height of tableview cell according to height of tableview height inside cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view.I has one custom cell in it.In that custom cell i have a `UITableView`.This child tableview can have cells & their content height can be dynamic.So i want calculate height of each cell & multiply the no of cells.After that height which is calculated give height to the main cell.

I wil use below logic

```
**Total height of main cell = height of each cell in child tableview * no of cells + header**
```

but i don't know how to do it.Please guide me how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[tableView reloadData] ; 
 CGSize tableViewSize= tableView.contentSize; // here you get your tablview's total height
```

**Get parent cell for your tableView**

```
   UITableViewCell *parentCellcell =(UITableViewCell *)tableView.superview.superview; // track your cell
   if (parentCellcell){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblViewParent indexPathForCell:cell];
    [tblViewParent reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray 
           arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
   }
```

Comment: How to pass to pass height of child table view to parent cell

Comment: reload that cell and pass this height.